# Is there any property of Hypergeometric function due to which we can prove following equality?

Tags: special-functions, hypergeometric-function

Is there any property of Hypergeometric function due to which we can prove following equality? $$-\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^2}{2}\left[\,_2F_1\left(m;-\frac{2}{k};1-\frac{2}{k};\frac{a}{u^k}\right)\right]=f(\infty)-f(u)$$ where $f(x)$ is defined as follows $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\,_2F_1\left(-\frac{2}{k},m;1-\frac{2}{k};-\frac{a}{x^k}\right).$$ where $a,u,m$ are positive values and $k>2$. In my thinking if the limit $\infty$ is zero and if we swap the positions of $-\frac{2}{k}$ and $m$ (in the first two arguments of Hypergeometric function then the answer is ok, but I am not sure how to prove these things). Thanks in advance.

On Limit $x\to \infty$:

We can write $f(x)$ as $$f(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac{2}{k}\right)_n(m)_n}{(1-\frac{2}{k})_nn!}\left(-\frac{a}{x^k}\right)^n$$ now if we expand it fof $n$ then the first term in the summation will cancel out with $\frac{x^2}{2}$ and the limit can be applied on the remaining terms and this will make sure that $f(\infty)=0$ because $n>0,k>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since
$_2F_1(a,b;c;z)
=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\dfrac{(a)_n(b)_n}{(c)_n}\dfrac{z^n}{n!}
$,
$_2F_1(a,b;c;z)
= _2F_1(b,a;c;z)
$
so swapping $a$ and $b$
is OK.

(added after OP's comment)

Pfaff's transformation
is
$_2F_1(a,b;c;z)
= (1-z)^{-a}\,_2F_1(a, c-b;c;\frac{z}{z-1})
$
or
$(1-z)^a\,_2F_1(a,b;c;z)
=\, _2F_1(a, c-b;c;\frac{z}{z-1})
$.
As $z \to 1$,
$\frac{z}{z-1} \to \infty$,
so that,
using your notation,
$\, _2F_1(a, c-b;c;\infty)
=\lim_{z \to 1}(1-z)^a\,_2F_1(a,b;c;1)
$.

Therefore,
if $a > 0$,
$\, _2F_1(a, c-b;c;\infty)
=0$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you guide how to show that $f(\infty)=0$ or what properties should be used to show that $f(\infty)=0$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not get the limit $\infty$ goes to zero part. When I apply Pfaff transformation then I get $\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^2}{2}\left(1+\frac{a}{x^k}\right)^{-\frac{2}{k}}\, _2F_1\left(-\frac{2}{k},1-\frac{2}{k}-m,1-\frac{2}{k},\frac{a}{a+x^k}\right)$ and I am unable to see how limit goes to $1$ and limit goes to $\infty$ in the arguments of Hypergeometric functions. Can you explain in detail. Many thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Although now I know how the limit infinity approaches zero (you can check my edited question) but still I do not get how Pfaff transformation can be used to prove it and I would like to learn that technique also. Many thanks for your help.